# Integral of $\sin^{-1}(1/2 - \sin x) dx$

Tags: integration

Obviously the solution exists for the integral $\int\sin^{-1}(\sin x) dx$, but does the solution exist for $\int\sin^{-1}(1/2 - \sin x) dx$? Or, for that matter, $\int\sin^{-1}(\alpha - \sin x) dx$ where $\alpha$ is some real number?

Or is this entirely dependent on the bounds? Integration by parts yields nothing useful, and I don't know enough complex analysis to do things with contour integrals, so I'm curious as to whether this has a closed form or not. I'm pretty sure the answer will have not be expressed nicely and not be full of real numbers, but I don't know how to show it.

Motivation: I'm trying to solve $\displaystyle\int_{1/2}^1 \frac{-\sin^{-1} u\,du}{\sqrt{(u+1/2)^2-1}}$, which after some substitutions becomes $\displaystyle\int_{\pi/2}^{\sin^{-1}(3/2)} i\sin^{-1} (1/2-\sin x)dx$. $\pi/2$ is obviously real, but $\sin^{-1}(3/2) = -i \ln(3i/2 + i\sqrt{5}/2) = \pi/2 - i\ln(3/2 + \sqrt{5}/2)$ is not, so I assume there has to be some sort of complex integration method to solve this.

Comment: Side remark: $\sin^{-1}(1/2 - \sin x)$ isn't always defined, eg if $x = -\pi/2$ then $1/2 - \sin x = 3/2$ isn't in the domain of $\sin^{-1}$.

Comment: A quick check on Wolfram reveals that the answer is likely no (by solution, I assume you mean a closed formula for the indefinite integral).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi indeed that is true, in fact one of the bounds I needed to use was $\sin^{-1}(3/2)$, which does have imaginary values. However, when I did numerical integration in Mathematica, the answer came out to a real number, which leads me to believe that certain contours (in my case, from $\pi/2$ to $\sin^{-1}(3/2)$) do result in real values. I just don't know how to find a closed form for those values, if they exist.